# Eclipse doesn't parse gcc output

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc

I use eclipse-3.5 as C/C++ editor for linux gentoo. The project is generated by CMake. As i know, the eclipse can parse GCC's output while building the project so you can click on any error message and jump to a string that caused that error. But it doesn't. Is this 3.5 feature?

Please don't suggest "to use another editor". I love eclipse's ctrl+tab and ctrl+click, code parsing and refactoring (rename variable) abilities :)

Comment: You can develop a C or C++ program without Eclipse (which is still an editor, and you could use others, like `emacs`, `gedit`, `geany`, `vim`, ....). BTW, with `emacs` you can compile inside it (with `M-x compile`) and click on an error message too....  Only the compiler (`gcc` or `g++` or `clang++`) is doing the real parsing.

Comment: I would think that this is a "toolchain setting" issue. You need to make sure you have the right configuration when you configure your project.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has this problem sometimes if you are using cmake and you use not existing paths in your cmake makefile. Check your cmake makefile, make sure every path that you use exists and then it should work.